Powershell terminal in VScode terminated with exit code: -1073741819
I'm trying to run a project on vscode but each time I open my terminal, it terminates on its own leaving this error code behind

"C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" terminated with exit code: -1073741819.


-1073741819 is exception code 0xC0000005: https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=0xC0000005 so the error is an access violation. Does that happen when you launch powershell directly as well ?

Are you writing any results?  You cmdlet does not permission to write to the System32 folder so you have to specify where to write results.

Yeah, same thing happens when i launch powershell directly.

@jdweng I don't understand what you meant

So that means the issue is not really related to VSCode, most likely something is loading from your PowerShell profile or it's an installed module or cmdlet causing this.

Yeah the issue was from my PowerShell. What I did was to download a new version and it fixed it
